# Get a nested json in URL session?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, urlsession

```
{
"data":{
"email":"ms.lightwave@example.com", 
"password":"123",
"token":""
} 
}



struct JsonResult: View{
    @State private var results = [GetData]()
    var body: some View{
        List(results, id: \.email){ item in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.password)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text(item.token)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            
        }.task {
            await loadData()
        }
    }

struct Response : Codable {
        var results: [GetData]
    }
    
    struct GetData: Codable{
        var data : [Result]
    }
    
    struct Result: Codable {
        var email: String
        var password: String
        var token: String
    }
    func loadData() async{
        guard let url = URL(string: "MYURL") else {
            print("invalid URL")
            return
        }
        do{
            let(data,_) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            // more code
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            {
                results = decodedResponse.results
            }
        } catch {
            print("Invalid Data")
        }
    }

}
```

i need to know if the codable structure is right according to the structure of data i gave ? and also the fetching in list ? please i need help in the URLsession i am still new and i barely know about url alot !

i would be grateful if you help me ! thank you verrrry much !!!!

Comment: `print("Invalid Data")` => `print("Error: \(error)")` and `try?` => `try` (and then remove the `if let`), and see the outputs...

Comment: i can't i have a problem in fetch list , an array within an array ! have an idea how to fetch a nested ? ! ,and you can't remove the if let and ? it says no decode response !

Comment: `let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data); results = decodedResponse.results`. I know that if the JSON you wrote is really the one you received (from `data`, is that really the output of `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)`? There is a difference between what's it's supposed to be and what it is in reality), that you'll get an error (and there is NO array in the JSON shown). But here, the whole point is to teach you to NOT ignore thrown errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSON there is no array involved (no `[]` at all).

The model corresponding to the JSON is

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let data : UserData
}

struct UserData: Decodable {
    let email: String
    let password: String
    let token: String
}
```

So the *data source* cannot be declared as an array. To avoid an optional type create an enum with associated values indicating a ***state***. The benefit is that you can show different views depending on the state

```
struct JsonResult: View {

    enum LoadingState {
        case idle, loading, loaded(UserData), failure(Error)
    }
```

this is the rest of the struct, consider that there is no `List` either because `UserData` is a single object.

```
    @State private var state : LoadingState = .idle
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch state {
                case .idle: EmptyView()
                case .loading: ProgressView()
                case .loaded(let userData):
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(userData.password)
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text(userData.email)
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                    
                case .failure(let error): Text(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }.task {
            await loadData()
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() async {
        
        state = .loading
        guard let url = URL(string: "MYURL") else {
            state = .failure(URLError(.badURL))
            return
        }
        do {
            let (data,_) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            // more code
            let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            state = .loaded(decodedResponse.data)
            
        } catch {
            state = .failure(error)
            print(error) // this shows the real DecodingError
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but when the error says your data couldn't be read because it is not in the correct format, and the terminal says The given data was not valid JSON. what do you interpret ?

Comment: *No valid JSON* means usually that you got an HTML server error.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Response : Decodable, Hashable {
    var results: [GetData]
}

struct GetData: Decodable, Hashable{
    var data : [Result]
}

struct Result: Decodable, Hashable {
    var email: String
    var password: String
    var token: String
}

enum RequestError: Error {
    case invalidURL
    case missingData
}

class JsonResultViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var response = [Response]()
    
    func performHTTPRequest(urlString: String) async throws{
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {throw RequestError.invalidURL}
        guard let (data, resp) = try? await URLSession.shared.data(from: url) else{throw RequestError.invalidURL}
        guard (resp as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else {throw RequestError.invalidURL}
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        guard let jsonResponse = try? decoder.decode([Response].self, from: data) else {throw RequestError.missingData}
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.response = jsonResponse 
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var results = JsonResultViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        List(results.response.indices, id: \.self){ index in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(results.response[index].results[index].data[index].email)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text(results.response[index].results[index].data[index].token)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            Task{
                do {
                    try await results.performHTTPRequest(urlString: "wwww.url.com")
                } catch RequestError.invalidURL{
                    print("invalid URL")
                } catch RequestError.missingData{
                    print("missing data")
                }
            }
        })
        
    }
}
```